# Twilio Fax is throwing 500 internal server error on StatusCallback in Django

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api, ngrok

I'm trying to set up a webhook that listens for status updates on faxes sent through Twilio's API.

The faxes are successfully sent but I am getting "500 Internal Server Error" codes on Ngrok.

```
POST /api/receive_fax_status_updates     500 Internal Server Error
```

This is what the twilio api function looks like:

```
    twilio_client.fax.faxes.create(
        to = fax_number,
        from_= twilio_number,
        media_url=fax_url,
        status_callback=status_callback_url,
    )
```

And here is what my Django endpoint handler looks like:

```
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ReceiveFaxStatusUpdates(View):
   def post(self, request):
       # Never executed, I have tried get as well.
       fax_status = request.POST['FaxStatus']
```

I haven't had any problems setting up webhooks for Twilio Messages/Calls. There is very little documentation on debugging and setting up Twilio Programmable Faxes.

Comment: The 500 error is coming from your app in this case. Are you able to make a successful post request to the endpoint using a tool like curl or Postman?

Comment: Wow! After downloading Postman, it turns out I needed to append an end slash my post request. Thanks  a lot!

Comment: Oops! Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Sidebar, but you can easily and programmatically manage `ngrok` from Python application using `pyngrok`. Django example [here](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#django).